# Email Piping - Read Attachment (.txt file)

Tags: php, email, cpanel, attachment, piping

I'm using email piping to save data sent by an end user through email; however, one requirement is that the user sends a text file with additional information.

Therefore, I need the email piping script to get the attachment, and read it. It's a simple text (.txt) document, base64 encoding, example:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-ID: <text_doc>
Content-Location: text_doc.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
```

This is my Email Piping script. The email passes through fine, I just need to get the attachment.

```
<?php
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

if(strlen($email)<1) {
    die(); 
}

// handle email
$lines = explode("\n", $email);

// empty vars
$from = "";
$to="";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$splittingheaders = true;

for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if ($splittingheaders) {
        // this is a header
        $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";
        // look out for special headers
        if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $subject = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $from = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $to = $matches[1];
        }
    } else {
        // not a header, but message
        $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
    }
    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
        // empty line, header section has ended
        $splittingheaders = false;
    }
}
```